# How to aggregate a list of raster in Composite Bands arcgis

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4

I created a list of raster using ListRaster. However, composite band tool does not support list input. I want aggregate the list of raster into one raster, is there any other tool to do it in ArcGIS(arcpy)?

Comment: Are the rasters *exactly* the same size (rows, columns, cellsize, Origin X,Y)? Have a read of https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/04/08/stacking-layers-of-imagery-in-arcgis/

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Is there a way to do it through arcpy?

Comment: Take your list and ';'.join(YourList) to turn it into semi-colon separated list for the composite bands tool or use GDALBuildVRT to make a virtual dataset.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I tried ";".join(list) but it cannot open the input dataset. I have not used gdal before I'll take a try. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried a list object for CompositeBands? The docs may be incorrect (wouldn't be the first time), provided your arcpy.env.workspace is set to the folder where the rasters are the tool *might* work with a list instead of a semi-colon separated list.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I've tried the list object, and tried a string listing all the files with semi colon. Neither of them works. Similar problem lies in Make Raster Layer function as well as it does not recognize the input when I call items using for loop from the list of raster.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I set the work space in where I have the raster files. It is a bit confusing  "set the folder where the rasters aren't the tool?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\MyRasterFolder' #My directory of rasters
rastList = arcpy.ListRasters()
myNewRast = arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rastList, r'C:\GIS\rasterCombined.tif')
```

(If this doesn't work for you, if you could post the code you're trying to run and the error message you're receiving, that will help refine things.)

Comment: it's interesting that the functions work under ArcGIS desktop but not on ArcGIS Pro.  ArcGIS Pro does not recognize list input.

Comment: I tried it in ArcGIS Pro with the same code above and it worked for me. Is there any chance that it doesn't like one of your rasters?

Comment: I tried exactly same input but it says my parameters are invalid. I checked pro's documents and it says for composite band function the input should not lists. It's good that it works on yours:)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194353/arcpy-make-raster-layer-function-does-not-produce-right-output    do you have any idea over this question?

Comment: Well, yeah, it's good that it works, but it's kind of weird. Huh. I posted an answer to your other question. See if that helps at all.